# pinax-project-account default password reset page with support@example.com

Tags: django, django-admin, pinax

I installed the pinax-project-account as through the link below.

https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account

Also I did go and change the site to `<mysite.com>` instead of `<example.com>`

However, the password reset page still shows the below

> If you have any trouble resetting your password, contact us at
>   support@example.com.

Is there anything that needs to be done to refresh? I run the web on gunicorn and nginx , and I already restarted the daemon and nginx.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's a default value within pinax's own source code. Try checking env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pinax_theme_bootstrap/**conf.py** (adjust to your environment as needed) and changing the `CONTACT_EMAIL` variable.

Alternatively, it may help in similar situations to add a new record to your underlying database table `django_site` with is what links the `SITE_ID` value in settings.py to its corresponding domain & name values. `SITE_ID` of 1 has default values "example.com" for both domain & name.

Additionally, though only somewhat related, make sure to change your `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` setting in your application's settings.py.